# 2-3 tree and how to build the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to build the constructor for the 2-3 tree. But I don't know how to approach this. Do we create a node with only one value and 2 pointers (left and middle) associated with that node from the beginning or a node with 2 values in it and 3 pointers (left, middle and right) ?

**Here is my 2-3 node class.**

```
template<class E>
class BNode
{
public:
    // I'm not sure if this is quite enough for the constructor
    BNode() {_right == nullptr;};

    typedef struct Entry
    {
        E value;
        BNode<E>* _left;
        // Constructor for the entry
        Entry();
    };

    E fValue() {return _first.value;}
    E sValue() {return _second.value;}
    BNode<E>* fLeft() {return _first._left;}
    BNode<E>* sLeft() {return _second._left;}

    //check if the node is 2 or 3 pointers
    bool IsThree() 
    {
        if(_first._left != nullptr && _second._left != nullptr
            && _second._right != nullptr)
            _three = true;
        else
            _three = false;
        return _three;
    }
    Entry fEntry() {return _first;}
    Entry sEntry() {return _second;}
    BNode<E>* right() {return _right;}

private:
    bool _three;
    Entry _first, _second;
    BNode<E>* _right;
};

template<class E>
BNode<E>::Entry::Entry()
{
    _left = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first declare the tree this way:

```
template<class E>
class BTree
{
public:
    BTree();
    ~BTree();

    class BNode
    {
    public:
        // I'm not sure if this is quite enough for the constructor
        BNode() {_right == nullptr;};

        typedef struct Entry
        {
            E value;
            BNode<E>* _left;
            // Constructor for the entry
            Entry();
        };

        E fValue() {return _first.value;}
        E sValue() {return _second.value;}
        BNode<E>* fLeft() {return _first._left;}
        BNode<E>* sLeft() {return _second._left;}

        //check if the node is 2 or 3 pointers
        bool IsThree() 
        {
            if(_first._left != nullptr && _second._left != nullptr
                && _second._right != nullptr)
                _three = true;
            else
                _three = false;
            return _three;
        }
        Entry fEntry() {return _first;}
        Entry sEntry() {return _second;}
        BNode<E>* right() {return _right;}

    private:
        bool _three;
        Entry _first, _second;
        BNode<E>* _right;
    };
private:
    BNode* root_;
};
template<class E>
BTree<E>::BNode<E>::Entry::Entry()
{
    _left = nullptr;
}
```

Then, `BNode()` should contain the one or two elements on the leaf, and `BTree()` should contain a list or/and an initializer list containing the list of objects (2 or 3 objects?) on each leaf if working with C++11. You should build the tree beginning with the root to the most down right leaf according to this drawing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree